# Technology stack for content site filled with hierarchical data

Tags: cms, web-services, programming

I'm thinking about starting a niche content project that would be filled with tons of highly hierarchical data.

- Interconnected blobs of text
- Annotations for the text
- Revision control
- User feedback
- Ranking of the content

What technology stack would be the most appropriate given that I'd like it to be open-source, simple, cheap to run and scale? Thank you!

Comment: I was looking into MongoDB, CouchDB and NodeJS but after a careful consideration decided to settle on PostgreSQL and Go for the backend. Please share your views!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description the project sounds like a Content Management System. I recommend going through a list of existing CMS software and picking one, paying attention its popularity and ease of customization, in addition to your stated preferences.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_frameworks

Adapting an existing CMS compared to writing your own can help a lot. If you indulge me in a politics joke, I want to say that the US health insurance e-shop is not built on Drupal and it did not go so well, whereas the website WhiteHouse.gov is based on CMS called Drupal (http://www.drupalshowcase.com/drupal-showcase/white-house) and it works fine ;)